Can't use custom hooks inside 'queryFn' which is a property of 'useQuery' (tanstack query)
I here want to fetch all 'products' using react query BUT

'build process' fails when using custom hooks inside 'useQuery', so it throws error in 'build process' but it works perfectly fine during 'development server'

const { data, isPending, isError, error } = useQuery({ queryKey: ["products"], queryFn: ({ signal }) => useHttp({ signal }), });
(Using signal to abort http request if user navigates to other page when request is being made)
Error message shown is the below one:
Error: React Hook "useHttp" is called in function "queryFn" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
Once again it works during development server but I'm not able to 'build' it due to the above error
useHttp looks like
`
export async function useHttp({ id, signal }) {
  try {
    const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

    const response = await fetch(url, { signal });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

`

According to the rules of hooks, hooks can only be called at top level in components or other hooks. You are calling the hook useHttp from queryFn which is a violation of those rules.
I can't give you any further guidance than that without more information on useHttp.
useHttp is not a hook, a hook is a function that uses other hooks inside of it, which useHttp doesn't. Since it isn't a hook, you should rename it to something that doesn't start with use and then your code will compile.

No, you cannot use React hooks inside the queryFn in React Query. React hooks can only be used in React function components or custom hooks that follow the rules of hooks. The queryFn is just a regular JavaScript function and doesn't have access to the React hooks.

Issue
Recall that React hooks are just plain old Javascript functions with some special rules placed and enforced around them as to when and where they can be called.


 Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.
 Do not call Hooks after a conditional return statement.
 Do not call Hooks in event handlers.
 Do not call Hooks in class components.
 Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.


useHttp is named like a React hook, i.e. with a "use"- prefix, and it is being called from a nested callback function which breaks the Rules of Hooks and isn't allowed.
Solution
Since it doesn't call any other React hooks it doesn't have to be named or called like one at all. You resolve this issue you can, and should, simply rename the utility function to anything that doesn't resemble a React hook function, e.g. that isn't named with the "use"- prefix. Your future self and other developers you work with will appreciate it.
Choose a descriptive name that indicates what the function does. In this case it appears to fetch products, so a good logical choice might be fetchProducts.
Example:
export async function fetchProducts({ signal }) {
  try {
    const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

    const response = await fetch(url, { signal });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const {
  data,
  isPending,
  isError,
  error
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["products"],
  queryFn: fetchProducts,
});

